# Netsuite Check inventory item vender list when adding line items in purchase order

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to create a client side script that checks an inventory item is actually supplied by the vendor that was selected in the body field of a purchase order. I can get field values for the current line item but don't know how to load the list of vendors that have been tagged to supply that item. Alternately it would be nice just to have the list not show any item that is not available from the selected vendor. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out so I thought I would post my solution. If anyone knows a better way and is willing to share please do.

Two change events I am worried about first when vendor is selected I load all the inventory items where that vendor is the preferred vendor. The second is when an 'item' is added or changed to check the against the vendors item list and show alert if needed.

```
var vendorItemList = '';
function fieldChange(type, name) {
    try
    {
        //on vendor change set vendorItemList
        if (name == 'entity')
        {
            //first check if current selected vendor supplies item selected
            var vendorId = nlapiGetFieldValue('entity');
            var vendorName = nlapiGetFieldValue('entity_display');

            //check if vendor supplies item
            var filters = [new nlobjSearchFilter('internalid','vendor','is', vendorId)];
            var columns = [new nlobjSearchColumn('itemid')];

            results = nlapiSearchRecord('inventoryitem',null,filters,columns);

            if (results != null)
            {   
                for(var i=0,l=results.length; i < l; i++) { 
                    var result = results[i];
                    var itemid   = result.getValue('itemid');

                    vendorItemList += itemid + "\n";
                }   
            }
        }   
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err.message);
    }

    try
    {
        if (name == 'item')
        {
            if (!vendorItemList.contains(itemText))
            {
                alert(vendorName + '\' is not a  vendor for \'' + itemText + '\' inventory item.');
            } 
        }
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err.message);
    }

}
```